# Криво работает поиск дубликатов

Tags: дефект, закрытие-вопросов, поиск

Пишу в поиск практически точное название вопроса (`как вернуть значение из асинхронной функции`), но он его не находит. А должен бы: [Как вернуть значение из асинхронной функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513037/178988)

[image: поиск]

[image: что надо было найти]

Comment: Видимо, уже дубликаты нельзя пометить в качестве дубликатов для нового вопроса, поэтому они в списке не отображаются. Надо искать ["Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/398802)

Comment: @dIm0n, если сунуть в поиск ссылку на вопрос, то всё находится и закрывается.

Comment: Криво работает поиск вообще. На SO это старая проблема, традиционный ответ: ищите в гугле.